# awk syntax '||' without 'if' - how does it work and why does it loop?

Tags: loops, if-statement, awk

I've been doing this university class and we got an assignment about awk. One exercise was to find the lowest value of a column, and I stumbled upon this line of code:

```
awk 'NR == 1 || $3 < min {line = $0; min = $3}END{print line}' file.txt
```

If number of lines read = 1 OR Element in third column is smaller than `min`, set `line` = line being read and `min` = Element from third column STOP print `line`.

I only know some basic python so far and I do not understand how the `||` works in this context. I know that it is a logical OR, but why is there no if?

Why does it loop without explicit commands like while, until or for?

Does `END` equals something like `else` in an if statement?

Comment: The basic structure of an awk statement is `expression {action}` and the program flow is `for each line of text, if the line matches the expression then execute the action`

Comment: END is not like an else statement.  It defines an action that occurs after all the lines of text have been read and processed.

Comment: More info available at the [awk info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) right here on stackoverflow

Comment: Type `man awk` on your Unix box. The awk syntax is `condition { action }` =  if `condition` is true then execute `action`, you just don't need to write `if ( ...)` around the condition.

Comment: wrt `Why does it loop without explicit commands like while, until or for` because that's what awk is designed to do. awk is not a general purpose language like C, it a language designed specifically to manipulate text so it does for you all of the common things that you'd have to code by hand in a general purpose language, e.g. looping reading inpu, splitting input lines into fields, etc.

Comment: I find ti helpful to think of AWK as a state machine-centric language, the code blocks are executed when the state described in the `condition` is true.

Answer (score 1):

As @WilliamPursell mentionned, the script is composed of a list of `expression { action }`. The special expression `END` is true after all the lines of the file have been processed (and `BEGIN` before). AWK works by reading the file line by line (by default) and for every line it evaluates every statement (you have only one) and checks if the expression is true. If it is true, the action is evaluated.

NR is the number of records read so far and in this case a record is a line of text. Since AWK will evaluate the statement `NR == 1 || $3 < min {line = $0; min = $3}` for every line in the file, it checks for every line if the expression is true i.e. if `NR == 1` (are we on the first line ?) or if `$3 < min` (the value of the third field is less than the minimum, `min` being implicitly initialized to 0 if it was not set on the first line) then we update `line` with the current line of text which has the minimum (`$0`) and the minimum `min` itself to the value.

The OR (`||`) is used to (1) initialize the minimum on the first line or (2) to update it with the new minimum.

When all the file has been processed, we output the line containing the minimum with `print line`.